# Recursion with C# Event

Tags: c#, events, recursion, prism

I'm debugging some code from the Microsoft prism library. Namely a class named ModuleCatalog:

```
public class AppModuleCatalog : IAppModuleCatalog
{
    private readonly ModuleCatalogItemCollection _items;
    private bool _isLoaded;

    public Collection<IAppModuleCatalogItem> Items
    {
        get { return (Collection<IAppModuleCatalogItem>)this._items; }
    }

    public AppModuleCatalog()
    {
      this._items = new ModuleCatalogItemCollection();
      this._items.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(this.ItemsCollectionChanged);
    }

    public virtual void AddModule(AppModuleInfo moduleInfo)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull("moduleInfo", moduleInfo);

        this.Items.Add(moduleInfo);
    }

    public AppModuleCatalog AddModule(string moduleName, string moduleType, string refValue, InitializationMode initializationMode, params string[] dependsOn)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull("ModuleName", moduleName);
        Argument.IsNotNull("moduleType", moduleType);

        AppModuleInfo moduleInfo = new AppModuleInfo(moduleName, moduleType);

        moduleInfo.DependsOn.AddRange(dependsOn);
        moduleInfo.InitializationMode = initializationMode;
        moduleInfo.Ref = refValue;
        this.Items.Add(moduleInfo);

        return this;
    }

    private void ItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Validated)
            return;
        this.EnsureCatalogValidated();
    }
    .
    .
    .

    private class ModuleCatalogItemCollection : Collection<IAppModuleCatalogItem>, INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

        protected override void InsertItem(int index, IAppModuleCatalogItem item)
        {
           InsertItem(index,item); 
           this.OnNotifyCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index));
        }

        protected void OnNotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (this.CollectionChanged == null) return;
            this.CollectionChanged(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

When this class is initialized, an AddModule method is called that will add the ModuleInfo  to Items property. What I have noticed is that the private class is then called and a recursive call is repeatedly made at the InsertItem method which of course causes an OverFlow Exception. Note that the getter from Items property returns _items

Could you please explain to me why the recursion is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [original source code](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#V5/PrismLibrary/Desktop/Prism/Modularity/ModuleCatalog.cs), the `ModuleCatalogItemCollection.InsertItem(int, IModuleCatalogItem)` method implementation looks like this:

```
protected override void InsertItem(int index, IModuleCatalogItem item)
{
    base.InsertItem(index, item);

    this.OnNotifyCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index));
}
```

Note the `base.InsertItem(index, item)` method call. This will call the base method implementation from the `Collection<IModuleCatalogItem>` class, not `this.InsertItem()`. So there is no recursive call at this place.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out yesterday. You beat me to the answer though =)